# Returning a pointer or reference to my current object from a insert_node function in a linked list program

Tags: c++, linked-list, this

I'm a beginner in c++. and I was writing a `link list` in which I can call my function for inserting nodes like this:

(assuming `a` and `b` and `c` are data which I want to insert in `link list`.

```
list.insert(a)->insert(b)->insert(c);
```

and I did it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    char letter;                     
    Node* next;     
};

class link_list {

private:
    Node* head;       
public:

    link_list() {             
        head = NULL;
    }
    link_list* insertNewNode(char item);
};


link_list* link_list::insertNewNode(char item) {
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->letter = item;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return this;
}

int main() {

    link_list list;
    list.insertNewNode('a')->insertNewNode('b')->insertNewNode('c');
    return 0;
}
```

in my `insertNewNode` function I'm returning a pointer to my current object.and it's working fine ,however I'm not sure if my method is right?

But I should also explain what happen , if instead of returning a pointer or reference to my current object ,I return my current object.

so I tried this:

```
class Node {
public:
    char letter;                     
    Node* next;     
};


class link_list {

private:
    Node* head;       
public:

    link_list() {             
        head = NULL;
    }
    link_list insertNewNode(char item);
};


link_list link_list::insertNewNode(char item) {
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->letter = item;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return *this;
}
int main() {

    link_list list;
    list.insertNewNode('a')->insertNewNode('b')->insertNewNode('c');
    return 0;
}
```

and then I received an error which said `list` should be a pointer ,so I changed my main to:

```
int main() {

    link_list *list;
    list = new link_list;
    list->insertNewNode('a')->insertNewNode('b')->insertNewNode('c');
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm still receiving this error which said here `list->insertNewNode('a')->insertNewNode('b')->insertNewNode('c');` **expression must have a pointer type** and these two errors:

> **1.type 'link_list' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'**
>
> **2.'->link_list::insertNewNode': left operand has 'class' type, use '.'**

so here is my questions for purpose of calling insert function like this `list.insert(p1)->insert(p2)->insert(p3);`, is my way in first program right ? and also is it even possible to return my current object for this purpose? and what would happen if I return current object?

PS:sorry for long question and also thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems fine. You are doing

```
link_list* insertNewNode(char) {
  // ...
  return this;
}
```

so that you can chain the insertions like this

```
list.insertNewNode('a')->insertNewNode('b')->insertNewNode('c');
```

You could also return a reference to the `link_list`, like this

```
link_list& insertNewNode(char) {
  // ...
  return *this;
}
```

and now chaining the insertions looks like this

```
list.insertNewNode('a').insertNewNode('b').insertNewNode('c');
```

Note that you shouldn't do something like

```
link_list insertNewNode(char) {
  // ...
  return *this;
}
```

because this will compile, but you would be returning a *copy* of the linked list, and the chaining would simply not work.

If your nodes would be added to the tail, the default copy constructor would make it *appear* as if chaining works, because the original `link_list` would see all `Nodes` added to the copy.

In your implementation, you are adding `Nodes` at the head, so the original link_list doesn't see `Nodes` added to the copy, and so the chaining doesn't appear to work. This is good, because the copies would leak the memory they allocate, even if you write a proper destructor.

Comment: "_because this will compile, but you would be returning a copy of the linked list, and the chaining would simply not work._" In the current code, as it's written, the chaining would seem to work, exactly as it would work, with returning a reference, due to not freeing (leaking) any allocated memory.

Comment: No, it [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/RD_Hj9) print the same answer.

Comment: sorry I don't understand why would changing works if my `Nodes` were added to the tail?

Comment: Changing would only *appear* to work. The best way to understand this is to draw out what each line of code does.

Answer (score 5):

1. Well, there's nothing criminal in your current method returning a pointer. Not something done very often, still quite compilable.
2. More idiomatic would be to return current object by-reference:

```cpp
link_list &insert(char elem) {
    return *this;
}
```

3. Your initial problem was that you changed method's return type, but retained `->` in `main()`. If you change `insert`'s return type to reference from pointer, then chained calls should be done via `.`, as you're working with objects and references to them, not with pointers.
4. Returning a copy of current object from a setter is not something that should be done, especially if you manage private resources on your own and haven't defined a proper copy constructor yet. Rather return a reference.

Comment: Technically, in the code as its written: even returning a copy would seem to work correctly, due to not freeing (leaking) any allocated memory. :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Returning by copy [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/RD_Hj9) work here.

Comment: so if I'm right only first node will be added since I using call by reference method,but for other nodes I'm using call by value method which means my list will only have one node ,and other nodes won't be added to list?

Comment: @hanie if you chain calls and return by-copy, consequently all, but the very first one, calls in a chain are applied to copies, not to the actual object.